# Angular Module not available when using karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a controller from my project and I'm getting a module not found error. I've looked at similar questions/answers but the solutions havent worked for me.

My Angular code is as follows:

```
angular.module('atMain')
   .controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'atDirApi', 'atServer', '$sce', '$filter','$routeParams', '$location', '$window', 
   function($scope, atDirApi, atServer, $sce, 
       $filter, $routeParams, $location, $window) {
       /* controller functions attached to $scope here*/
   }]);
```

My karma test looks like:

```
describe('', function() {
    var MainCtrl;
    beforeEach(module("atMain"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        MainCtrl = $controller("MainController");
    }));

    it('should showImage to !showImage', function() {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('MainController', { $scope: $scope }); 
        $scope.showImage = false;
        $scope.showFunc();

        expect($scope.showImage).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

My karma.conf file has the following:

```
        files: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'app.js',
        'services/server-service/server-service.js',
        'components/main/main-controller.js',
        'components/main/main.js',
        'tests/*.js'
    ],
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'atMain' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.module('atMain')
```

retrieves the existing Angular module. When used in this manner the module has to be already registered with

```
angular.module('atMain', [...])
```

This is what [`$injector:nomod`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) error message says.